# Formula to get a sub table where the values in a column match a certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a formula to get a sub table out of the main table, of the rows in which the balance column has a value greater than zero.

```
NameClass   Date    Pre Balance July    Van Fine    Total   Received    Balance
ABC Pnur    13-Jul-18   2,000   1,000               3,000   3,000       0
ABD Pnur    10-Jul-18   2,000   1,000       50      3,050   1,000       2,050
ABE Pnur    16-Jul-18   7,370   1,000               8,370   8,370       0
ABF Pnur    26-Jul-18   7,370   1,000               8,370   8,370       0
```

[image: Screenshot of main table]

Comment: Edit the post  & put data in Tabular form,, it's quite confusing!! Reload the Image also.

Comment: What about a pivot table? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: You could use an advanced filter

Answer (score 1):

*To get a Sub table out of the Main table, of the Rows in which the Balance Column has value greater than zero, you need to do the followings.*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$166:$I$169, SMALL(IF((INDEX($I$166:$I$169, , $A$163)>0), MATCH(ROW($A$166:$I$169), ROW($A$166:$I$169)), ""), ROWS(A172:$A$172)), COLUMNS($A$1:A1)),"")
```

- Put Zero in Cell `A163`.
- Write above written array formula in Cell `A172` 
  finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` then fill Right & 
  Down.

[image]

**Note,** *adjust cell references in the 
  formula as needed.*